# how to make android devices cpu usage to 100%? and memory usage to 100%?

Tags: android

```
i'm doing hardware testing on android devices , 

and thinking about this :
```

1. make CPU usage to 100%.
2. make memory(RAM) usage to 100.

if i create a lot of threads and services , sure it does.

but is there a normal way to test?